# Ionic 3 App Self Update

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

Please I am Stacked on an issue with self update plugin of ionic. I added app update plugin of ionic 3. After setting the whole thing up. I get this error when building the application. Any Help will be much appreciated

[image: error thrown during building the application]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the provider_paths.xml file in your android build at platforms/android/res/xml/provider_paths.xml ?

This is what the content of my file is, but it may be looking for something additional in yours:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```